# how to stop 3d carousel on mouse click event

Tags: jquery

I use 3d carousel of http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/carousel.html
Anyone suggest me how can i stop this carousel on mouse click event with fix position?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopImmediatePropagation.28.29)

Comment: is there any function define in *.js file?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly reset the rotation timer. Something like:

```
clearInterval(rotationTimer)
```

or perhaps

```
clearInterval(el.carouselCfg.rotationTimer)
```